# Data structure for a huge dataset

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections, dataset

I need to make an efficient data structure for a class which stores a Collection of size varying from 50,000 to 100,000 of values.

```
class TypeData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Collection<double> Data{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, user wants to perform some operations on this data, the operation then replaces the actual values in collection with '0'. For example

```
Before operation:
3.4
5.6
66.71
101.44
3.567
345.09

After operation:
3.4
0.0
0.0
101.44
0.0
345.09
```

Now, user wants to revert that operation. Then I have to remove all the 0.0 and have to placed the original values on those indexes in collection.

Question 1: 
How to keep track of changed indexes? Do i need to keep an another list containing all the changed indexes? 
Question 2:
How to improve the data structure of this class so that it can accommodate thousand of instances i.e

`List<TypeData> dataList = new List<TypeData>();` // the size this list can grow to 5000

Answer (score 1):

If you have to *undo* operation only once, then solution with holding *active/actual* values of Tim Schmelter is the right one.

If you need multiple *undo's*, then you have to implement a *history*. Same way you could also provide *redo* possibility.

With some assumptions *undo* can be actually very easy task. If number of items in the list between *undo* is not changed, then you can save in the history (which is basically another list) `index` and `value` for all your changes. Undo operation will go through the history, take index and just restore the value.

If number of items will be changed, then easiest would be to save a complete *state* of data, by making a copy. This, however, is memory consuming operation, though still can be implemented if you consider to use database or file to save such states.

Other solution would be to implement *operations*, which you can save in the history. You still have to save *state*, but it would be only of that size, which *operation* is required (to example, in case of deleting item you don't need to store whole list, only index and value of deleted item). Undo in this case will looks like a reading from history last operation and performing it backward (or you can have *inverted* history from start, ready for undo, to example, in case of deleting item, you instead save insert operation). In case of list manipulation the basic list of possible operation could be: clear, insert at, delete at, change value at.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: How to keep track of changed indexes? Do i need to keep an
>   another list containing all the changed indexes?

I wouldn't store a `Collection<double>` but a `Collection<CustomType>` which stores the value, the curent state and the history (if any).

For example:

```
public class TypeData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public enum State
    {
        Unassigned,
        Original,
        Modified
    }

    private double _Value = 0.0d;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            if (CurrentState == State.Unassigned)
                CurrentState = State.Original;
            else
                CurrentState = State.Modified;
            _Value = value;
            _ValueHistory.Add(value);
            if (_ValueHistory.Count > MaxHistoryCount)
                ClearValueHistory();
        }
    }

    private List<double> _ValueHistory = new List<double> { 0.0d };
    private List<double> ValueHistory
    {
        get { return _ValueHistory; }
        set { _ValueHistory = value; }
    }

    private int _MaxHistoryCount = int.MaxValue;
    public int MaxHistoryCount
    {
        get { return _MaxHistoryCount; }
        set { _MaxHistoryCount = value; }
    }

    public void ClearValueHistory()
    {
        if (_ValueHistory.Count > 1)
            _ValueHistory.RemoveRange(0, _ValueHistory.Count - 1); // keep last
    }

    private State _CurrentState = State.Unassigned;
    public State CurrentState
    {
        get { return _CurrentState; }
        private set { _CurrentState = value; }
    }

    public void RevertOperation(int numRevertCount = 1)
    {
        int newRevisionIndex = _ValueHistory.Count - 1 - numRevertCount;
        if (newRevisionIndex < 0) newRevisionIndex = 0;
        double val = _ValueHistory[newRevisionIndex];
        _ValueHistory.RemoveRange(newRevisionIndex + 1, _ValueHistory.Count - 1 - newRevisionIndex);
        this._Value = val;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here's is sample data and an examplary reverse-operation:

```
var listOfData = new List<TypeData>{ 
    new TypeData {
        Name = "TestData",
        Data = new List<Data> 
        {
            new Data { Value = 1.5 }, new Data { Value = 2.4 }, new Data { Value = 1.2 },  new Data(),
            new Data { Value = 0.7 }, new Data { Value = -4.7 }, new Data { Value = 0.0 }, new Data { Value = 4711}
        }
    }
};

foreach (var td in listOfData)
{
    foreach (var data in td.Data.Take(10))
    {
        data.Value = 4711.4711;
    }
}
foreach (var td in listOfData)
{
    foreach (var data in td.Data.Take(10))
    {
        data.RevertOperation();
    }
}
```

> Question 2: How to improve the data structure of this class so that it
>   can accommodate thousand of instances i.e

Why do you need to improve it? I would keep it as it is. I doubt that it needs too much memory. Otherwise you should decide whether you buy more memory or you should use a database instead.

Comment: I could have used struct for that, having a boolean indicating a changed value. But I have some hard requirements, there are two types of operation, the first operation will mark the values to 0.0 at random indexes, and the second operation will mark the 0.0 in a range of index. So what if user only wants to revert the first operation. boolean cant tell, what operation made this value to 0.0

Comment: enum DataType
{
   Original,
   Operation1,
   Operation2
}

struct Data
{
   double value;
   DataType type;
}

Will this work?
What if some new requirement comes in future or may be third operation?

Comment: To be honest, i would use a database instead. However, i have edited my answer to show a possible implementation of a class that stores the history of this value. Note that it should give you an idea, it's not tested thoroughly.

Comment: Actually, I cant use database here in this workflow. The actual scenario is, user has survey data stored as a blob in a database, user wants to load data for 5000 surveys. I just deserialized  each survey data, bring it in to the memory and display it on the graph. So before displaying this on to the graph I have fill all collection<double> :(